# What about image of infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was reading complex analysis from John B. Conway, there we have a theorem which states that cross ratio of four complex numbers is real if and only if they all lie on a circle.

In the proof of this theorem, we have used the fact that image of $\mathbb R_{\infty}$ under any Mobius transformation is a circle. But while proving this fact they have only shown the image of $\mathbb R$ is a circle, what about the image of infinity?

Here is the proof
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is this $\mathbb C_{\infty}$? The Riemann sphere? (also known as the complex projective line)

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb C_{\infty}$ denotes Riemann sphere.

Answer (score 0):

You can deduce the image of $\infty$ by continuity of the application~; there is no need for an extra argument. In other words, if the image of the real line without the point at infinity is a circle minus a point, then the image of the real line with infinity will be a circle with that point.

The key argument is really that Moebius transformations are invertible maps of the Riemann sphere preserving those "generalized circles" (which when you see the Riemann sphere as a geometrical sphere embedded in three-dimensional real space, those "generalized circles" are simply hyperplane sections of that sphere). I really recommend this "visualisation" [proof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY), it is extremely well done. When you know that these are Moebius transformations, it is clear that it maps hyperplane sections to hyperplane sections since it corresponds to rigid transformations of three-dimensional real space.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

I am recently reading this book, and I had the same question. I believe that some details are missing from this proof, so I want to use this answer to explain these details. The notation is the same as the one used in Conway's book.

Two cases are discussed in the book. In the first case, it is assumed that $a\overline{c}\in \mathbb{R}$. Define $L:=\{\omega:\text{Im}(\alpha\omega-i\beta)=0\},$ which is a line (there is a typo on the book). The book then shows that $S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})-\{\infty\}\subset L$. Our goal is to prove that $S^{-1}(\mathbb{R}_\infty)=S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\cup S^{-1}(\{\infty\})=L\cup\{\infty\}$. If $c=0$, then $S(\infty)=\infty$, $\infty=S^{-1}(\infty)$, and $\infty\notin S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$. It can also be easily seen that $L\subset S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})-\{\infty\}\Rightarrow L=S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})-\{\infty\}$.  Hence,  $S^{-1}(\mathbb{R}_\infty)=S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\cup S^{-1}(\{\infty\})=(S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})-\{\infty\})\cup\{\infty\}=L\cup\{\infty\}$.

If $c\ne 0$, then $S(-d/c)=\infty$, which suggests that any $\omega\in S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})-\{\infty\}$ cannot be equal to $-d/c$ (otherwise, $\omega=-d/c\Rightarrow S(\omega)=\infty\Rightarrow S(\omega)\notin \mathbb{R}$, which is a contradiction). Consequently, we can know that $L-\{-d/c\}=S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})-\{\infty\}$. Besides, $a\overline{c}\in \mathbb{R}$ implies that $a/c\in \mathbb{R}$ and since $S(\infty)=a/c, \infty\in S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$. Lastly, I claim that $-d/c\in L$. I calculated $\alpha(-d/c)-i\beta$ by using Mathematica (see the picture below) and the result is $d\bar{b}+b\bar{d}-2ad\bar{d}/c$, which is indeed a real number. Now we can deduce that $S^{-1}(\mathbb{R}_\infty)=S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\cup S^{-1}(\{\infty\})=(S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})-\{\infty\})\cup \{\infty\}\cup\{-d/c\}=(L-\{-d/c\})\cup\{\infty\}\cup\{-d/c\}=L\cup \{\infty\}.$

Now we can consider the case that $a\bar{c}$ is not real (which implics that $c$ cannot be 0). Define $C:=\{\omega:|\omega|^2+\bar{\gamma}\omega+\gamma\bar{\omega}-\delta=0\}$, which is a circle. The book proves that $S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})-\{\infty\}\subset C$, and our goal is to show that $S^{-1}(\mathbb{R_\infty})=C$. We first show that $\{\infty\}\notin S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$. We can prove this by contradiction. If $S(\infty)=a/c=r$ for some $r\in\mathbb{R}$, then $a\bar{c}=rc\bar{c}\in \mathbb{R}$. This is a contradiction with our assumption. Thus, $S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\subset C$. We also need to show that $S^{-1}(\infty)=-d/c\in C$. Again, I used Mathematica to calculate $|d/c|^2+\bar{\gamma}(-d/c)+\gamma\overline{-d/c}$, which is indeed equal to $\delta$ (see the picture below). We now know that $S^{-1}(\mathbb{R_\infty})=S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\cup S^{-1}(\{\infty\})=S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\cup\{-d/c\}\subset C$. The last thing that we need to check is $C\subset S^{-1}(\mathbb{R_\infty})$. This can be proved by noticing that $C-\{-d/c\}\subset S^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$.

[image]